# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'E'

Tags: python

I was trying to use an "Input" function to prompt a user to select an option.

```
print("1. Default Data Sheet\n2. Upload Data Sheet\nE. Exit")
option = input("Please select an option: ")
while option != "E" and int(option) < 1 or int(option) > 2: 
    option = input("Please select a valid option: ")
if int(option) == 1:
    dataset = pd.read_csv("portfolioStock.csv")
    with open("portfolioStock.csv", newline='') as file: 
        for row in csv.reader(file):
            stock.append(row)
elif int(option) == 2:
    filename = input("Please enter filename with the extension:")
    dataset = pd.read_csv(filename)
    with open(filename, newline='') as file:
        for row in csv.reader(file):
            stock.append(row)
elif option == "E":
    print("Press enter to return to menu.")
```

However when I debug the code, input 1 and 2 works well but an input E generated an error message "**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'E'**"
I have tried to print out the type of my input and it gives me "str" as expected. So I have no idea where my code goes wrong. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: If the option is `E`, you try to convert it to a `int` first. In that case your program crashes because it's the string `E` and not a number.

Comment: Use a while True - loop, use try: except: to catch validation error of option = int(option) - check for "E" in the except block and break from it.

Comment: Why convert to int at all ... check against the strings without converting to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

> ```
> while option != "E" and int(option) < 1 or int(option) > 2:
> ```

will **always** convert `option` to `int` to verify the second half of the `and` condition.

You do not even need the integers - simply compare for string values.

---

**Not using integers at all - they are not needed for your usecase:**

```
print("1. Default Data Sheet\n2. Upload Data Sheet\nE. Exit")
while True:
    option = input("Please select an option: ") # add .upper()?
    if option not in ('1', '2', 'E'):
        print("Invalid choice. 1, 2 or 'E' allowed.")
        continue
    
    if option == "1":
        print("    Choice --> ", option)
    elif option == "2":
        print("    Choice --> ", option)
    else:  # "E"
        print("    Choice --> ", option)
        print("Quitting\n")
        break
```

---

Or do it like it is done in Change your logic according to [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response):

**Using try: .. except: ... and integer conversion:**

```
print("\n1. Default Data Sheet\n2. Upload Data Sheet\nE. Exit")
while True:
    try:
        option = input("Please select an option: ")
        option = int(option)
        if option not in (1, 2):
            raise ValueError() # outside bounds
        print("    Choice --> ", option)
    except ValueError:
        if option == "E":
            print("Quitting\n")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid choice. 1, 2 or 'E' allowed.")
```

(Indentical) Output for both codes:

```
1. Default Data Sheet
2. Upload Data Sheet
E. Exit
Please select an option: 4
Invalid choice. 1, 2 or 'E' allowed.
Please select an option: e
Invalid choice. 1, 2 or 'E' allowed.
Please select an option: 1
    Choice -->  1
Please select an option: 2
    Choice -->  2
Please select an option: E
    Choice -->  E
Quitting
```

Comment: Thank you so much！I managed to solve this issue using your method.

Answer (score 0):

"E" is a string, not a number. When you choose "E", the code stops at the while condition. Try to convert the variable "option" as a string type. You must change also the while condition

```
print("1. Default Data Sheet\n2. Upload Data Sheet\nE. Exit")
option = input("Please select an option: ")
while (option != "E" and str(option) != "1" and str(option) != "2"): 
    option = input("Please select a valid option: ")
    
if str(option) == "1":
    print("you press 1")
elif str(option) == "2":
    print("you press 2")
elif str(option) == "E":
    print("Press enter to return to menu.")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please run code before posting. Yours does not work.

Comment: I'm sorry. Unfortunately, I don't have time to try again. So I'm going to delete the post.

Comment: I edit and try my code: now it should work. Sorry for the trouble I make, Patrick

Comment: The str() around `str(option) != "1" and str(option) != "2"` is not needed. `input()` always returns a string. You can do `while option not in ("E","1","2"): option = input("Please select a valid option: ")`